# How can I programmatically start a jetty server with multiple configuration files?

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

In other words, what is this equivalent to:

java -jar start.jar etc/jetty.xml jetty-plus.xml

I'm using Jetty 6.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with Jetty 7, Jetty 8, and Jetty 9.
Can you upgrade?

Note: Jetty 6 was end of life'd back in 2010.

```java
package jetty;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration;

public class EmbeddedViaXml
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // The configuration files
            List<URL> configs = new ArrayList<>();
            configs.add(new File("jetty.xml").toURI().toURL());
            configs.add(new File("jetty-plus.xml").toURI().toURL());

            // The properties
            Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
            props.put("jetty.home",new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")).getCanonicalPath());

            Server server = load(configs,props);
            server.start();
            server.join();
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Server load(List<URL> xmlConfigUrls, Map<String, String> props) throws Exception
    {
        XmlConfiguration last = null;
        // Hold list of configured objects
        Object[] obj = new Object[xmlConfigUrls.size()];

        // Configure everything
        for (int i = 0; i < xmlConfigUrls.size(); i++)
        {
            URL configURL = xmlConfigUrls.get(i);
            XmlConfiguration configuration = new XmlConfiguration(configURL);
            if (last != null)
            {
                // Let configuration know about prior configured objects
                configuration.getIdMap().putAll(last.getIdMap());
            }
            configuration.getProperties().putAll(props);
            obj[i] = configuration.configure();
            last = configuration;
        }

        // Find Server Instance.
        Server foundServer = null;
        int serverCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < xmlConfigUrls.size(); i++)
        {
            if (obj[i] instanceof Server)
            {
                if (obj[i].equals(foundServer))
                {
                    // Identical server instance found
                    continue; // Skip
                }
                foundServer = (Server)obj[i];
                serverCount++;
            }
        }

        if (serverCount <= 0)
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Load failed to configure a " + Server.class.getName());
        }

        if (serverCount == 1)
        {
            return foundServer;
        }

        throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Configured %d Servers, expected 1",serverCount));
    }
}
```