# Embedding Jetty 9.3 with modular XmlConfiguration

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I am migrating from Jetty 8.1.17 to Jetty 9.3.9. Our application ***embeds*** Jetty. Previously we had a single XML configuration file `jetty.xml` which contained everything we needed.

I felt that with Jetty 9.3.9 it would be much nicer to use the modular approach that they suggest, so far I have `jetty.xml`, `jetty-http.xml`, `jetty-https.xml` and `jetty-ssl.xml` in my `$JETTY_HOME/etc`; these are pretty much copies of those from the 9.3.9 distribution. This seems to work well when I use `start.jar` but not through my own code which embeds Jetty.

Ideally I would like to be able to scan for any jetty xml files in the `$JETTY_HOME/etc` folder and load the configuration. However for embedded mode I have not found a way to do that without explicitly defining the order that those files should be loaded in, due to `<ref id="x"/>` dependencies between them etc.

My initial attempt is based on [How can I programmatically start a jetty server with multiple configuration files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817375/how-can-i-programmatically-start-a-jetty-server-with-multiple-configuration-file) and looks like:

```
final List<Object> configuredObjects = new ArrayList();
XmlConfiguration last = null;
for(final Path confFile : configFiles) {
    logger.info("[loading jetty configuration : {}]", confFile.toString());
    try(final InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(confFile)) {
        final XmlConfiguration configuration = new XmlConfiguration(is);
        if (last != null) {
            configuration.getIdMap().putAll(last.getIdMap());
        }
        configuredObjects.add(configuration.configure());
        last = configuration;
    }
}

Server server = null;
// For all objects created by XmlConfigurations, start them if they are lifecycles.
for (final Object configuredObject : configuredObjects) {
    if(configuredObject instanceof Server) {
        server = (Server)configuredObject;
    }

    if (configuredObject instanceof LifeCycle) {
        final LifeCycle lc = (LifeCycle)configuredObject;
        if (!lc.isRunning()) {
            lc.start();
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get Exceptions at startup if `jetty-https.xml` is loaded before `jetty-ssl.xml` or if I place a reference in `jetty.xml` to an object from a sub-configuration `jetty-blah.xml` which has not been loaded first.

It seems to me like Jetty manages to do this okay itself when you call `java -jar start.jar`, so what am I missing to get Jetty to not care about what order the config files are parsed in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order is *extremely* important when loading the Jetty XML files.

That's the heart of what the entire `start.jar` and its module system is about, have an appropriate set of properties, the server classpath is sane, and ensuring proper load order of the XML.

> Note: its not possible to have everything in `${jetty.home}/etc` loaded at the same time, as you will get conflicts on alternate implementations of common technologies (something `start.jar` also manages for you)

Comment: Is there any way that I can easily reuse/call function code from start.jar in my embedded app, where I can present it with a list of XML files and it can figure out the order etc for me?

Comment: you can't have start.jar work with just xml files. it has to work with modules.

Comment: you are embedded, declare the xml load order in your embedded code and use it.  no need to be dynamic about it.

Comment: Well yes we embed Jetty. But it is useful to us if people can modify the Jetty config by just adding/changing XML files in our `jetty/etc` folder. Could we perhaps adopt the module mechanism from start.jar as well?

Comment: the `start.jar` uses a `${jetty.base}` to handle modification needs to `${jetty.home}` content.  (Note: do **not** change/edit/modify/delete content in the `${jetty.home}` directory)

Comment: Can I not just set $jetty.base = $jetty.home, and somehow use functions from start.jar to determine what to load?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114770/discussion-between-joakim-erdfelt-and-adamretter).